# Dynamic Method Dispatch and inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I was reading a JAVA-book and came across the Dynamic Method Dispatch. But it was  a little confusing for me(maybe because I am a newb). The book said it was based on the principle: a superclass reference variable can refer to a subclass object.

```
    class X{
    void display()
    {
       System.out.println("This is class X");
    }
    }

    class Y extends X{
    void display()
    {
        System.out.println("This is class Y");
    }
    void play()
    {
        System.out.println("PLAY!");
    }
    }

    class k{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    X obj1 = new X();
    Y obj2 = new Y();
    X ref  = new X();

    ref = obj1;
    ref.display();
    //output is :This is class X

    ref = obj2;   //Using the principle stated above
    ref.display();
    //output is :This is class Y

    ref.play();  //Compiler error:Play not found 
    //well it must be because ref is of X type and for X no methods of its subclass "Y"
    //is visible
    }
    }
```

So i wanted to ask that if 
        play()
is not visible then why
        display()
 of Y is visible??

Comment: `ref` is of type `X`.  Thus you can only access method signatures defined in `class X`.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it in terms of *promises*. `X ref` *promises* that what it holds (if anything) is of type `X`. Of course, the `Y` is also of type `X`, that is what subclassing means: every instance of `Y` is an instance of `X` as well (plus some adjustments and extra features). However, the `play` method can't be called through it as the contents are not *known* to be a `Y`, according to the language definition.

You can *explicitly cast* the `ref` to a `Y` and then call `play` on it:

```
((Y) ref).play();
```

This is safe because each object in Java knows its own *real* type. If the object reference was to an instance of the wrong type (e.g., `obj1`) you will get a `ClassCastException` when you run the code. (If you know C, this is *completely different*.)

Answer (score 0):

A parent class reference holds the property of a child object which are inherited from parent. Hence you can call all those methods from a parent reference holding a child object, which are inherited and overriden by the child class.

In short, reference will decide what methods can be called, the object it is holding will decide, which method(parent/subclass) will be called.

> So i wanted to ask that if play() is not visible then why display() of
>   Y is visible??

display is visible because that is a method of Parent reference. But play belongs to only child, hence it is not visible to the Parent.

Answer (score 0):

Static type checking ensures, that you can call those methods only, which belong to the static (declared) type of the reference. That is why you cannot call .play() via a reference with type X.

However, dynamic method dispatch ensures, that if a method is overridden in a subclass, then that specific method will be called dynamically (at run time).

Answer (score 0):

Before execution, Java programs are processed by compiler. Compiler makes sure, among many other things, that only existing methods are called. In the case above, compiler only knows that *ref* is of type *X*, as declared, and that type *X* has no method *play*. It does not track all the assignments and does not takes into consideration that *ref* was assigned by *obj2* of type *Y* - such tracking is impossible in general case, as it may depend on runtime data, unavailable at compile time.

On the other hand, method invocation at runtime relies on actual type, which can be extension of declared type. The very same code, issued by the compiler, can call different implementations of method *display*, depending on the actual type of the object referenced by the variable *ref*. Compiler, however, checks that method *display* exists for all possible types of objects which may be assigned to *ref*.